# F#: purpose of SwitchToThreadPool just before async return

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, asynchronous, f#

In the MS docs for [Async.SwitchToNewThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370351.aspx) one of the examples given is:

```
let asyncMethod f = 
    async {  
        do! Async.SwitchToNewThread() 
        let result = f() 
        do! Async.SwitchToThreadPool() 
        return result
    }
```

What is the purpose of switching to the thread pool immediately before a return statement? I understand why you might want to switch from a dedicated thread to the thread pool when the async block has more work to do but that is not the case here.

This is not part of the main question, but I'm also curious to know why SwitchToNewThread and SwitchToThreadPool return an Async. Is there ever a use case where you would not want to immediately "do!" these tasks? Thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The example could be clearer, because it doesn't demonstrate any real scenario.

However, there is a good reason for switching to another thread before `return`. The reason is that the workflow that calls your function (e.g. `asyncMethod`) will continue running in the context/thread that you switch to before returning. For example, if you write:

```
Async.Start (async {
  // Starts running on some thread (depends on how it is started - 'Async.Start' uses
  // thread pool and 'Async.StartImmediate' uses the current thread
  do! asyncMethod (fun () -> 
      Thread.Sleep(1000) ) // Blocks a newly created thread for 1 sec
  // Continues running on the thread pool thread 
  Thread.Sleep(1000) }) // Blocks thread pool thread
```

I think the pattern used in the example isn't quite right - asynchronous workflows should always return back to the `SynchronizationContext` on which they were started (e.g. if a workflow is started on GUI thread, it can switch to a new thread, but should then return back to the GUI thread). If I was writing `asyncMethod` function, I'd use:

```
let asyncMethod f = async {  
    let original = System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current
    do! Async.SwitchToNewThread() 
    let result = f() 
    do! Async.SwitchToContext(original)
    return result }
```

To answer your second question - the reason why `SwitchTo` operations return `Async<unit>` and need to be called using `do!` is that there is no way to switch to a different thread directly. The only points where you get the rest of the workflow as a function (that you can execute on a new thread) is when you use `do!` or `let!` The `Async<T>` type is essentially just some object that gets a function (the rest of the workflow) and can execute it anywhere it wants, but there is no other way to "break" the workflow.

Comment: Thanks Tomas. Your answer gave me some good insight on what's really going on

Comment: what if `let original = System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current` is `null`? Seems to always be null when I use `Async.Parallel |> Async.Start` from the gui thread (and within the `async` block do some work, then switch to the gui context I got a hold of before starting the `async`s in parallel). Switching back to null after having switched to the gui context and performed some updates doesn't seem to do any harm, but does it get me off the gui thread?

Comment: nevermind, I was able to empirically confirm that switching to null does take you off the gui thread (not sure where it goes though). Thanks anyways!

Comment: @StephenSwensen, If `SynchrnoizationContext.Current` is `null`, and you call the `Post` or `Send` method, it will execute on a thread pool thread. - see also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx

Comment: what happens if there is an exception before switching back to original synchronization context?